# Erro ao criar uma tabela MySQL

Tags: mysql

eu criei uma tabela no Power Designer como mostra a abaixo

```
create table BANCO
(
   COD_BANCO            integer not null auto_increment,
   NOME_BANCO           varchar(50),
   AGENCIA_BANCO        integer,
   CONTA_BANCO          integer,
   GERENTE_BANCO        varchar(20),
   FONE_BANCO           varchar(10),
   primary key (COD_BANCO)
)
type = InnoDB;
```

porém gerou esse erro

```
error 1064 (42000)You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type = InnoDB' at line 11
```

é porque o Power Designer estar trabalhando com MySQL 5 e o que estar instalado no meu pc é MySQL 5.5

como faço para resolver esse problema? vou ter que instalar a versão MySQL 5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Troque `type` por `engine`. O `type` era usando em versões antigas do MySQL.

> "*The older term TYPE is supported as a synonym for ENGINE for backward
>   compatibility, but ENGINE is the preferred term and TYPE is
>   deprecated.*"
>
> O TYPE, termo mais antigo, é suportado como um sinônimo de ENGINE para
>   compatibilidade com versões anteriores, mas ENGINE é o termo
>   preferido e TYPE está obsoleto.

[Fonte](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-innodb-tables.html)

Answer (score 0):

Para corrigir isto no power designer basta editar o DBMS e vá em `MYSQL50::Script\Objects\Table\Options`.
Role o texto para cima e você vai achar algo como isto no campo Value:

```
type = %s : list = BDB | HEAP | ISAM | InnoDB | MERGE | MRG_MYISAM | MYISAM, default = MYISAM
```

Edite esta linha deixando assim:

```
engine = %s : list = BDB | HEAP | ISAM | InnoDB | MERGE | MRG_MYISAM | MYISAM, default = InnoDB
```

Veja que alterei também o `default` para `InnoDB`, assim quando você criar a tabela ele já insere como `engine = InnoDB`.
Feito isto basta salvar como MySQL5.1 para que não sobreponha o DBMS do MySQL5.0.